# Understanding why $|g(z)| < 1$ for all $z \in \Delta$ in the proof of Scwar'z Lemma in Palka's book *An Introduction to Complex Function Theory*

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

This question concerns the proof of theorem 3.14 in pages 172-173, namely why the Maximum Modulus Principle implies that $|g(z)| < 1$ for all $z \in \Delta$ for a certain open disk $\Delta$ when $|g(z)||z| \leq |z|$ for all $z \in \Delta$.

To be specific, the theorem is that

> Let  $f$ be an analytic function in the open disk $\Delta := \Delta(0, 1)$ such that $f(0) = 0$, $\forall z \in \Delta: |f(z)| \leq 1$. Then $|f'(0)|\leq 1$ and $\forall z \in \Delta:|f(z)|\leq |z|$.

Palka begins by defining $g:\Delta \to \mathbb{C}, g(z) =  \frac{f(z)}{z}$ when $|z| \in (0, 1)$ and $g(0) = f'(0)$. Such a $g$ is continuous in $\Delta$ and analytic in the punctured disk $\Delta^*(0, 1)$. Then Palka states the following:
[image]

(**Question:**) What I don't understand is why the Maximum Modulus Principle implies that $|g(z)| < 1$ for any $z \in \Delta$ when $g$ is not a constant function with a modulus one. The given Maximum Modulus Principle is that

> Let a function $f$ be analytic in an open connected set $D \subset \mathbb{C}$. Suppose that there exists a point $z_0 \in D$ such that for all $z \in D:|f(z)| \leq |f(z_0)|$. Then $f$ is constant in $D$.

Comment: If $|g(z)| \leq 1$ and if it is not true that $|g(z)| < 1$ what can you say? Doesn't it tell you that $|g(z)|=1$ so the maximum of $|g(z)|$ is attained at $z$?

Answer (score 2):

Are you ok with the proof that $|g(z)|\leq 1$ on $\Delta$? With this at hand, suppose that there is a $z_0\in \Delta$ with $|g(z_0)|=1$. Can you get a contradiction from this when $g$ isn't constant?

Comment: Yes I am okay with the proof you asked. To be certain that I understood the proof correctly, is the reason that such a $z_0 \in \Delta$ cannot exist the fact that then $g$ would have a modulus 1 on $\Delta$, when we know that for some $z \in \Delta$, $|g(z)| < 1$?

Comment: @CartesianBear Since $|g|\leq 1$ on $\Delta$, if there exists $z_0\in \Delta$ such that $g(z_0)=1$, then $g$ attains it's maximum in $\Delta$ and therefore is a constant, by the maximum modulus principle. It's exactly the formulation you quote at the end of your post, $|g(z)\leq |g(z_0)|$ ($=1$). Therefore such $z_0$ cannot exist, meaning $|g(z)|<1$ on $\Delta$.

Comment: I see. In that case, I still have to ask what condition does $|g(z)| = 1$ on $\Delta$ violate? I understand clearly what immediate effect the MMP has: when attaining its maximum on $\Delta$, $|g(z)|$ would be a constant. What I fail to understand is what is the prior assumption that is contradicted by this fact?